# How to check if page is home page in Magento 1.8.0.1 with cache enabled?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I tried following code in Magento 1.8.1.0 in a phtml file.

File containing the code is  `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml`

XML file for this phtml file is `catalog.xml`

```
<default>


    <reference name="top.container">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms.top.callout" before="-">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>top_callout</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
    </reference>
    ----
    -----
</default>
```

.

```
  $route = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName();

    if($route == 'cms' && $action == 'index'):
        echo "home page";
    endif;
```

.

```
$is_homepage = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage();

if($is_homepage)
{

 echo "home page";

}
```

Means I am getting condition true i.e "home page" on every page even if it is not home page.
Is there any precise way to find out the Home page

**If I disable Magento cache it works fine**

Comment: Can you tell in which template you write this code? What it mean "not work well"? thx

Comment: I don't see the catalog/navigation/custom_leftnav.phtml in your layout. try to replace catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml by the good one.

Comment: A clean method will be to create a new module and update the layout with the setTemplate method.

Comment: have you refresh your cache?

Comment: @apouey yes I refreshed the cace

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); 
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if ($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    echo 'Homepage';
}
```

Comment: Problem is, Magento caches the block, so this value is the same on every page.

Answer (score 0):

hi you need change and controller name is you logic

```
/**
 * get Controller name
 */
 $controller=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
     if($route == 'cms' && $action == 'index'&& $controller='index'):
            echo "home page";
        endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change home page identifier as per yours.

```
<?php
                if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()=="home")
{
// Your code comes here !
}
?>
```